# The Egress to switch port is direction a or direction b?

Tags: switch, switchport

I have a doubt about the switch port Egress direction and Ingress direction.

[image]

you see the upper have Egress rate limit.

I want to know the Egress to switch port is direction a or direction b?

[image]

Comment: Port egress traffic it's a traffic from port to host (a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingress and egress are terms (normally) used with network devices like switches and routers. So, switch egress is (a).

"Egress *to* switch port..." implies the POV from the server (or anything else but the switch).

Comment: what's the meaning of `POV`?

Comment: "point of view" ;-)